# Load different images based on user screen aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I have a page that displays full-width and full-height (fullscreen) images (HTML-UP Lens theme).

I use images exported to work best with 16:9 screen aspect ratio. However, I would like to support other aspect ratios as well (e.g. 1680x1050 screen sizes, ratio 16.8x10.5). Since I want to use all available space, I would need to create different images based on screen size and load these, based on the users screen aspect ratio. How do I do this?

- `scrset` seems to relate to pixel-size, e.g. beyond 800px width, load higher resolution images, but nothing is mentioned for loading different images base on aspect ratio
- `<picture>` tag is only supported recently, e.g. for Firefox since end of 2022

Comment: Do you definitely want to create different images? You will never have enough to cover all possible viewport sizes. Instead look at object fit or background size cover and perhaps just think of having a portrait and a landscape friendly version.

Comment: Thank you. While the answer from `fat penguin` seems the right one, I tend to follow your suggestion - looking at all the variations and the effort to keep different files and formats in sync is just to much of a hassle.

Comment: As the user can alter viewport size to anything they like at any time on many devices there is no way you can create enough images to suit all cases, so I don’t see how the answer below could possibly work.

Comment: I mean, theoretically you could supply common Aspect Ratios, e.g. 1:1, 4:3, 16:9, this would maybe catch 80%. The others would be assigned on a best fit approach. Anyway, I still agree that it is a solution for a question that should not have been asked in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use CSS @media query with `aspect-ratio`

e.g.

```
@media (aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
 // css styling here
}
```

more info over at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio)